# Como colocar menu Navigation Drawer embaixo da Action Bar?

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

Olá, iniciei um novo projeto com o padrão Navigation Drawer, um projeto padrão do Android, ele vem com o menu que passa por cima da Action Bar, assim:

[image]

Gostaria queria que ele ficasse como nas imagem abaixo:

[image: Quero que o menu fique assim, atrás da Actino Bar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não modifique seu seu arquivo `AndroidManifest.xml`, deixe ele como está, dessa maneira:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="br.com.myapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".BlankActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Obs:** veja que acima estou usando o pacote de minha aplicação  `package="br.com.myapplication"` mude para o seu pacote se não você terá um erro na hora de fazer Build.

---

Modifique seu arquivo `activity_main` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

    <include  layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

---

Modifique seu arquivo `content_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

     <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Digite seu texto aqui ou externalize!"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

Modifique seu arquivo `app_bar_main.xml`, dessa maneira:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

---

Arquivo `styles.xml`:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>


    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

---

Lembre-se de adicionar as dependências, lá no Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.com.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
}
```

---

Veja como ficou:

[image]    [image]

---

Depois faça um Sync e depois um Build <kbd>Ctrl+F9</kbd>.

Ou ainda, você pode iniciar um novo projeto com o padrão `Master/Detail Flow`.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Eu tinha feito isso para retirar o header, funciona porem o navigation drawer ainda fica por cima só que sem o header. Atualmente esta assim: http://i.imgur.com/YkeHeIa.png

Comment: essa imagem é do meu celular rodando a aplicação

Comment: Deu alguns bugs, o app entra dentro da status bar e fica preto a letra em cima: http://i.imgur.com/7VuiB4l.png

Comment: continuou a mesma coisa, de qualquer forma obrigado por tentar ajuda

Comment: no gradle não tinha compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0' e o style não mexi, esta igual ao seu mas mesmo assim continua, sera q tem haver com uma splash screen que fiz ? tem algum local que possa upar meu projeto pra você ve o código inteiro ?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40420/discussion-between-igor-oliveira-and-paulo-henrique-nery-oliveira).