# Por que minha ActionBar devido a um erro fica dentro da minha StatusBar?

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

Iniciei um novo projeto padrão no Android, fiz igual esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/130711/como-colocar-menu-navigation-drawer-embaixo-da-action-bar/130739#130739) para a minha `ActionBar` ficar em cima do menu padrão `NavigationDrawer`, agora, a minha `ActionBar` entra dentro da `StatusBar` e a fonte fica preta, eu não mexi em nada o código esta o padrão com as modificações da resposta acima que funcionou para ele.

Como resolver este problema da `ActionBar` que devido a um erro está entrando na `StatusBar`?

[image: Como ele fica]

Meu arquivo `MainActivity.java`:

```
package com.libertynetworkbrasil.libertyapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>


    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

Styles.xml v21

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Activity_Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        android:paddingTop="15dp" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.libertynetworkbrasil.libertyapp"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

        <include  layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: coloquei, ta o padrão que vem no modelo, não mexi nele

Comment: ja tinha testado ficou a mesma coisa, eu te mandei no chat um código que fiz no xml que consegui abaixar o app da uma olhada lá

Comment: Olá! Você pode adicionar seus arquivos `style.xml`? Se você tiver mais de um, adicione-os separadamente

Comment: @sicachester adicionei

Comment: Sua `application` e sua `activity` no `AndroidManifest` estão utilizando qual tema? Poderia adicionar o `layout.xml` da sua `Activity`?

Comment: minha application usa tema @style/AppTheme e minha activity @style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" vou adicionar o activty_Main

Comment: Igor, conseguiu resolver seu problema ou precisa de mais alguma informação?

Comment: @AckLay infelizmente não funcionou, mas deixei do jeito antigo mesmo. ja terminei esse app

Answer (score 1):

Tenta recriar o projeto utilizando o Android Studio. Um passo muito importante é atualizar o [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) as vezes tem versão "bugada". Como você está utilizando um sample padrão não é para ter erro.

Comment: ja estou utilizando a ultima versão do android studio, e o sample funciona,  mas pra fazer oque quero tem q fazer uma modificação no código e dai da este erro

Answer (score 0):

Descobri o motivo do erro a partir da API 21, sua Action Bar vai se comportar assim de modo `transparente` porque você viu ali no arquivo `styles.xml(v21)` ela está com a cor transparente, então mude seu arquivo `styles.xml(v21)`, assim:

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Mude seu arquivo `styles.xml` para esse estilo, como está abaixo:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>


    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

Você tem graves erros(onde está a seta) em sua `main_activity.xml` veja abaixo:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            -> android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            -> android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            android:paddingTop="15dp" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        -> xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.libertynetworkbrasil.libertyapp"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:openDrawer="start">
```

Solução para os erros acima, mude a sua `main_activity.xml`, exatamente assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

    <include  layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Depois de ter concertado acima, faça um `Sync Gradle`, depois um `Build Project` e depois um `Build .apk` e ai você volta a rodar seu app em uma vm ou no celular.

**Obs:** lembrando que se você está testando no celular, você terá que desinstalar a versão de seu .apk com erro, excluir o .apk errado que você copiou para pasta de seu celular, copiar o novo .apk para sua pasta e instalar de novo para ver se agora está tudo ok!

Comment: Criei outro projeto com mesmo padrão de navigation drawer mas não ta indo como ficou agora: http://prntscr.com/bafc8k

Comment: content_main.xml

Comment: Fiz tudo do outro tópico, e fiz desse tambem porem ta assim: http://prntscr.com/bafgbu ele continua entrando dentro da status bar.

Answer (score 0):

Acrescente na raiz do seu layout `Activity_Main.xml` o seguinte atributo:

```
android:fitsSystemWindows = "true"
```

> O `fitsSystemWindows` é um atributo interno para ajustar o layout de
>   exibição com base em janelas do sistema, tais como a barra de status.

Boa sorte!